# Encrypt a string with C# and decrypt it on iOS and Android

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a WCF Web Service with C# and .NET Framework 4.0. I'm also developing an iOS and Android client to connect with it.

On server side, I have to generate an aleatory password, encrypt it, and send it back to iOS client or to an Android client.

I don't know how can I encrypt a string with .NET Framework. Searching on Internet, I see that there are algorithms to do it: MD5, RSA, etc. (I'm not sure if I have understood how to encrypt a string because I haven't do a string encryption yet).

If I use MD5 to encrypt a password, what do I have to do to decrypt it on iOS and on Android?

What do you recommend me?

Comment: Use SSL to encrypt the connection. Far stronger than anything you'll manage to build by yourself.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I want to store password encrypted on database and also on iOS and Android devices.

Comment: For the transfer send the password in plain of SSL (don't forget to validate the server certificate). For the database, use a specialized password hash (PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt). See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for details. In .net the easiest hash is `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with ~20000 iterations which is an implementation of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creating an md5 hash of a Keyword is easy in .net:

```
MD5 hashKey = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
var hashedKey = hashKey.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password"));
```

Note: hashed key is byte array, you can build a string from it or do further encrpytion (f.e. change into digits, convert it to hex...). You need `using System.Security.Cryptography;`

On Ios/Android you have to do the same, encrypt the string with the MD5algorithm (which is alway the same, thats why it works) and compare the two results.

Comment: But it's a bad idea in at least four different ways. 1) It's fast. You need to use a slow iterated scheme like scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2. 2) It doesn't have a salt 3) It silently corrupts non ASCII passwords 4) While MD5 isn't broken in this context, it's still preferable to use a stronger hash like SHA-2 (as a builing block in PBKDF2)

Comment: @CodesInChaos I know... i just posted an example how to use md5 (which was the basic question). Sure this cannot be the full solution incl. salt etc. But i agree with you in point 3... didnt thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting the string is easy in .Net. You can use the built in System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.

Here is a link for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx

Here is a question very similar to yours regarding encrypting/decryption between languages.. mfanto has a good answer.

[Best practices for passing encrypted data between different programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246307/best-practices-for-passing-encrypted-data-between-different-programming-language)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't find where is that very similar question.

Comment: @VansFannel Sorry, forgot to post the link :(

Comment: Encryption is pretty hard in .net. It only offers low level functions. It's difficult to combine those into a secure scheme. In this case MD5 is obviously a bad choice.

Comment: I do agree with you, but his question was how to encrypt a string in .Net w/ MD5 so I answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how serious your encryption must be? MD5 is not a serious thing. And as for RSA, you should take into the account that this is an asyn method of encryption which consumes a pair of public and private keys. Depending on your goals it would be possible to say whether RSA is good enough for you or not. And of course, never use public libraries for encryption(including MS) if you develop something serious.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote RSA and AES implementation using CommonCrypto, implementation is done in order to be interoperable with .NET

Check it out

https://github.com/ozgurshn/EncryptionForiOS